# How to find a specific data in Json using foreach loop?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I want to get `no_kerja`, `tajuk_mohon`, `status`, and `nm_status`.

```
[
  {
    "status": "string",
    "tajuk_mohon": "string",
    "tkh_btal_tgguh": "string",
    "tkh_buka_iklan": "string",
    "tkh_jk_sdg": "string",
    "tkh_lulus_jkpr": "string",
    "no_kerja": "string",
    "jurutera_civ": "string",
    "no_kerja_baru": "string",
    "bldg_id": "string",
    "jns_perolehan": "string",
    "keterangan_projek": "string",
    "lampiran": "string",
    "lulus_ruang": "string",
    "no_lulus_ruang": "string",
    "pemohon_id": "string",
    "status_akhir_serah": "string",
    "sumber": "string",
    "status_keterangan": "string",
    "syarat": "string",
    "nm_status": "string"
  }
]
```

How do I use `foreach` loop to get the specific data using PHP curl.?

Answer (score 0):

```
// your json
$json = '[{ 
    "status": "string", 
    "tkh_buka_iklan": "string", 
    "no_kerja": "string", 
    "no_kerja_baru": "string" 
}]';  

$array = json_decode($json, true);  

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value['no_kerja']; // get no_kerja
    // echo $array['tajuk_mohon']; // get tajuk_mohon
    // echo $array['status']; // get status
    // echo $array['nm_status']; // get nm_status

}
```